# Adding item to taxonomy menu vocabulary in the create content form?

Tags: drupal, menu, taxonomy

I've implemented taxonomy menu in Drupal, and trying to set it up so that it is pretty easy for the user to add new items to the vocabulary from the create content form instead of having to administer the vocabulary itself.

So far, all I can manage is the default behaviour of displaying the existing items.

Edit:

Enabling the 'tags' option for the vocabulary does not allow the desired effect - I want the parent/child structure and drop-down menu in the create content form as well as the ability to add a new tag to that drop-down.

A bit more explanation as to why - I'm trying to create an image gallery using a hierarchy of tags (so, sports > soccer > match on 31st May) - the problem is that the general content creator for the site is non-technical, and I'd like to avoid having to make them work through the taxonomy/vocabulary items interface directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Hierarchical Select module](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).

Take a look at the last demo at the following page:
http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called "tags" in Drupal. You want to check the "Tags" checkbox on the vocabulary edit page and that will change the interface on the content entry forms so users can add new terms/tags.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm aware of tags - however, using this option replaces the drop-down menu with an input box - I need to have both. I'll make this clearer in my question.

Comment: Sounds like maybe Taxonomy Other is what you want:

http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_other

Comment: getting closer, thanks - but it puts the new category in the root of the vocabulary. Thanks for the suggestions, though - useful things to know